# Write CSS from jQuery within a for loop

Tags: jquery

My script needs to dynamically create a stylesheet in the  section of the page (rather than put inline styles on each element, because I need to override these styles with media queries later on).

**The Code**

```
for (var i=0; i<theElements.length; i++){

    $(theElements[i]).not('.responsive-wrap').each(function(i, elem){
        var theWidth = $(this).width();
        var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();

        $(this).addClass('element' + [i]);

        $("#dynamicStylesheet").text('.element' + [i] + ' {max-width: ' + theWidth + 'px;}');
    });
}
```

**The main question is:**

This completely overrides the text in the `#dynamicStylesheet` each run of the loop (so when I load the page there is only one rule for `.element22`). How can I make it ADD the text without overwriting?

**Sub-questions for bonus points:**

- This works for the most-part, but ONLY when `[i]` is in square
  brackets. Why is this?

  Do I need the `for loop` here, or is `.each(function(){})` essentially
  creating a `for loop` anyway? There's another `each` function below this one inside the `for loop` that I haven't posted to keep it succinct.

Comment: should do a cross browser check of your concept, have had problems in versions of IE trying to update style tag text and changes not occurring to elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, a few things. Assuming that `theElements` is an array of HTML elements, the `each` is unnecessary. But that doesn't seem to be the case, since you say `element22` is showing up (your code as its written would only create `element0` over and over again if `theElements` was an array of HTML elements). So apparently `theElements` is an array of arrays, or an array of jQuery objects. Which is weird given its name, but let's power through.

As others have mentioned, you're overwriting the text every iteration, which is bad. Building a string is slightly better, but you're still doing repeated string concatenation, which is slow. If we had to do this, we should append to an array and then join it together at the end (which is faster, since appending to a string creates the entire string from scratch every time).

```
var css = [];
for (var i = 0; i < theElements.length; i++) {
    $(theElements[i]).not('.responsive-wrap').each(function(i) {
        var theWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).addClass('element' + i);
        css.push('.element' + i + ' {max-width: ' + theWidth + 'px;}');
    });
}
$("#dynamicStylesheet").text(css.join('\n'));
```

Now, that works, and will do what you want. But this is almost definitely not the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Dynamically building CSS on the client is not good, unless you're writing something like a CSS editor. There are much easier ways to solve whatever problem led you down this path.

If creating a client-side stylesheet is *absolutely vital*, then there are better ways to do this, too. Create a single CSS rule that applies to all the elements of the elements of `theElements` (wow, look at that sentence). That's not possible if they're chosen randomly, but if you arrived at them through some logical query you can use the same one in CSS.

As far as the `[i]` thing goes -- I don't know what to tell you. Due to the weird way JavaScript stringifies arrays, they're equivalent, and if `i` doesn't work for you then there's something very wrong. I would be using `i.toString()` if I were you, but `i` should work fine.

#### Edit

If `theElements` is an array of tag names, this can be simplified to:

```
var tagNames = theElements; // clear variable names are important!
var css = [];
$(tagNames.join(',')).not('.responsive-wrap').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('element' + i.toString());
    css.push('.element' + i.toString() + '{ max-width: ' + $this.width() + 'px; }');
});
$("#dynamicStylesheet").text(css.join('\n'));
```

Comment: To clarify - theElements is an array with `"div", "section", "table"` etc in it, so just strings. This script is a plugin to make old static websites fully responsive, so there's a lot of CSS writing going on, The reason I'm writing a stylesheet is because the first step is to find out what the site is "meant" to look like at full-width before we start changing things.

Comment: For whatever reason, it's still not working without the for loop/not really working at all. The whole script is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rFR69/

Comment: @Jascination without the HTML and a whole lot more specificity about the error message, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: There is no error message - just nothing is being added to the style section. The script is entirely javascript + css, no html. HOWEVER after changing using your edited code, it now works. Cheers! Now just have to find out why. (I'm new to Javascript/jQuery!)

Answer (score 2):

I would not add the text during each iteration.  Instead, build a string and then add it to the element.  This also improves performance.

You do not need the for loop.

```
var cssString = '';
$(theElements).not('.responsive-wrap').each(function(i, elem){
    var theWidth = $(this).width();
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();

    $(this).addClass('element' + [i]);

    cssString += '.element' + [i] + ' {max-width: ' + theWidth + 'px;}';
});

$("#dynamicStylesheet").text(cssString);
```

Comment: While it's nice not to modify the DOM every iteration, this isn't really optimal, as string concatenation has a linear cost (so the performance of the whole thing is quadratic). It's generally good to avoid repeated string concatenation whenever possible.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work - quite possibly because theElements (as noted elsewhere) is an array of strings with tag names inside like 'div', 'section', 'article' etc. With this code (and variants I tried) the stylesheet was not updated at all unfortunately.

Comment: @IanHenry Could you point me towards some stats on the performance cost of string concatenation? I always thought it was a pretty minimal cost approach.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Because JavaScript strings are immutable, when you concatenate A and B, you're actually creating a new string of length A + B. When you then concatenate C, you're creating a new string of length A + B + C. Concatenate again and you're creating A + B + C + D. Each time it becomes more and more expensive to do; a classic Schlemiel algorithm. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html This is why many languages (though not JS) provide classes like Java's StringBuffer or C#'s StringBuilder.

Comment: @IanHenry depending on the browser/computer, string concatenation takes minimal time to compute (millions of ops/sec) and in some cases the browser optimizes for this. http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation/14.  So, string concat is faster than adding to a DOM element (I think we can agree on that).  Readability is preferred when performance gains are negligible.

Comment: @asawilliams String concatenation is fast. Repeated quadratic string concatenation is slow. It requires O(n^2) space instead of O(n). Does it matter in this case? No. It's just a good habit to get out of.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a quick way to add the text instead of overwriting it each time

```
$("#dynamicStylesheet").text(
             $("#dynamicStylesheet").text()
             + '.element' + [i] + ' {max-width: ' + theWidth + 'px;}');
```

As for the for loop, yes the `each` should be all you need. Maybe add a counting variable if you need the number. I also set `$("#dynamicStylesheet")` to a variable outside of the loop so jQuery doesn't have to look for the element each time through - it's for increased performance.

```
var i = 0,
    stylesheet = $("#dynamicStylesheet");

$(theElements).not('.responsive-wrap').each(function(){
    var theWidth = $(this).width();
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var elemName = "element" + i;

    $(this).addClass(elemName);

    stylesheet.text(
             stylesheet.text()
             + '.' + elemName + ' {max-width: ' + theWidth + 'px;}');
});
```

**EDIT**

If `theElements` is an array of tag names, something like this would work better than my original.

```
var i = 0,
    stylesheet = $("#dynamicStylesheet");

$.each(theElements, function(){
  if( !$(this).hasClass('responsive-wrap') ){

    var theWidth = $(this).width();
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var elemName = "element" + i;

    $(this).addClass(elemName);

    stylesheet.text(
             stylesheet.text()
             + '.' + elemName + ' {max-width: ' + theWidth + 'px;}');
 }
});
```

Not tested, but should work..

Comment: I'm curious why you (and asawilliams) think that the nested loops are not necessary. My jQuery is rusty; what am I missing? It seems to me that this is not equivalent to what the OP is describing.

Comment: I was under the assumptions originally that `theElements` was a standard selector, like `.responsiveDivs` or `div.red`. Turns out OP actually has an array of tag names, so this way would need to be modified (see update).